# Wireless Access Point (connected to pfSense) is only fast when using Double NAT?

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, speed, wireless-access-point, pfsense

I've been troubleshooting this problem for several days now and I am completely stumped.

I have a cable modem connected directly to pfSense (dedicated hardware on SuperMicro motherboard). pfSense is then connected to a Dell PowerConnect 2420 managed switch.

My wireless access point (Apple Airport Extreme, but also tried ASUS RT-66U) is connected to the Dell switch.

When I configure the wireless access point in [Bridged] mode, I'm getting very slow speeds across my network. I'm using iperf3 from my MacBook Pro (802.11ac) to my desktop PC (wired gigabit). I also use www.speedtest.net.

However, when I enable DHCP and NAT on my wireless access point (creating a double NAT situation), my speeds are almost tripled and everything works flawless.

What's going on here? I really don't want to enable double NAT but I am completely confused...

Answer (score 2):

Routing and NAT are layer-3. Bridging is layer-2. Bridging is not what you want. Look up broadcast and collision domains to understand bridging. You want to avoid an unneeded, additional layer-3 network that will result in double-NAT.

A WiFi Router with the routing/gateway features disabled or unused is now considered a "WiFi AP", which functions as a network switch. You could also exclusively use the LAN ports of a WiFi router since they function as a switch. (Double-)NAT will only happen when traffic goes between the WiFi-router's LAN and WAN ports. If traffic is LAN to LAN, double-NAT is avoided regardless of the layer-3 routing features still enabled. Assign the WiFi AP a static IP (disable DHCP client) and disable DHCP server functionality.

The RT-N66U actually has an AP mode which makes use of all the ports, LAN and WAN, effectively having all ports function as if they were all LAN ports. This actively disables most of the unneeded layer-3 features.

Go get a good networking book. Just a year ago I thought I my networking knowledge was above-par because I knew the differences between a hub and switch... Man was I blissfully, dangerously ignorant.

Comment: "_Just a year ago I thought I my networking knowledge was above-par because I knew the differences between a hub and switch... Man was I blissfully, dangerously ignorant._" Finally, someone will admit it! Kudos to you. Everyone I know seems to be a "network expert".

Comment: I think what you are saying is what I'm doing (i.e. TL;DR): On the AP, set up Wi-Fi SSID, security, channels, etc. (because you may not have access to the GUI without manually resetting the AP), then disable DHCP on the LAN ports. Connect a LAN port on the AP to the pfSense LAN (in this case I believe Dell 2420) and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Paul Good points. Configuring the WiFi AP with a static IP assures you will know the address and yeah, the WiFi AP's DHCP server should be disabled.

Comment: I actually don't configure any IP on the AP, but I've only been configuring DD-WRT based routers for this purpose. None of my DD-WRT routers are responsive after I disable DHCP and no longer have a device with a lease they created. Even when I'm on the same subnet with a static IP and the AP disconnected (and rebooted), they don't respond, so I just manually reset them.

Comment: Strange. You should be able to access it. Every WiFi router I have owned was capable of assigning itself a static IP, stock firmware or tomato.

Comment: I've been wanting to move away from DD-WRT just for these strange behavior type things, but I have a box of Buffalo routers, so, oh well. But, yes, the routers are non-responsive after disabling DHCP. I've just gotten used to it. The flip side is that without DHCP, they suddenly become incredibly stable, lasting up to one year without needing a reboot (that's the longest I've gone between blackouts longer than the UPS can last).